# Android InMobi tutorial

Tags: android, ads, inmobi

OK.

Have anyone already implement InMobi (Android SDK v2.0) into Android app?
I'm having trouble doing it. I have read InMobi Android SDK v2.0 Installation and Integration manual and can not make InMobiAndroidSampleApp to work, to show same ads.
The only useful information I have is that `adRequestFailed` method is called two times.
I have proper `siteId` method implementation (returns string of InMobi App ID).

Any ideas? Working examples? Tutorials?

10x

Answer (score 4):

I'm from the InMobi Operations team. The problem is that the latest Adwhirl release does not have the updated InMobi Adapters. Can you try with the following versions of the Adwhirl Adapter and the InMobi SDK?

- [Updated InMobi Android SDK](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16117/InMobi_Android_SDK_Rel_v2.3.zip)
- [Update Adwhirl Adapters](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/30899852/InMobiAdapter.java) - This is for the Source version of Adwhirl SDK
- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/30899852/adWhirl/AdWhirlSDK_Android_3.0.0.jar – This is for developers using the Compiled version of the Adwhirl SDK (has the adapters of other ad networks which come by default with the Source SDK)

Answer (score 1):

Just to let you know that the latest InMobi tutorials for Android can be found on our new Wiki.
http://developer.inmobi.com/wiki/index.php?title=Android

Answer (score 0):

Obviously Ad network providers (as also Ad Mediators like AdWhirl is) need some time to register/take effect acter change. Today Ads working for me with full support of AdWhirl.
When you implement Ads in your app/game you need to wait some time to take effect.